# From tutorial: Break flow. Question, answer, question. To Question,answer,answer

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

The following dialogue tutorial has a system where there is a greeting, list of questions, and then an answer. The system uses IDs to tie each question to an answer and then return to a list of questions(new or the previous list).

https://youtu.be/Tjb_5v00xBY

I want to find a way to change the format so an answer can lead to another answer.

Ex.
Questions: where are you from?, what’s your name?

Answers: Atlanta, Julie

Now normally the system will go to a new list of questions or the one list above. Instead I want both answers to lead to a new answer.

Ex.

Answers: Why did you ask that?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Let me know if anyone has a better solution, but I simply added a new enum dialogue command titled normal answer, and a new variable in the answer structure titled Answer ID. I made a macro that simulated an event calling the answer ID (after a question was clicked), and added it as a enum execution macro. So when a answer has the normal answer enum, then it calls a listed answer instead of a question.

Confusing i know, but if you watch the tutorial maybe you can understand the explanation better.